# How to filter formulas based on dates?

Tags: excel, excel-2010

I have the following spreadsheet which  I want to do for loging my trades.

http://screencast.com/t/LJVbSIfbE

In a second spreadsheet, I have some stats with formulas like
MAX
MIN
SUM
AVERAGE
AVERAGEIF
COUNTIF

etc

However, I want to be able to filter in the summary spreadsheet with dates, for example:
Last week dates, with this week dates, then I can compare my performance week by week or month by month

http://screencast.com/t/ulYLVDuEq

Comment: You can use ordinary numeric operands (`>`, `=>`, `<=`, `<`, `<>`, `=`) on date values. For string values you can use the worksheet function `DateValue(string_date)` to convert strings to dates, e.g., `=DateValue("8/10/2013")>A2` would return `TRUE` in your worksheet.  You can likely use these operands with your `COUNTIF`/ etc. functions.

Comment: I am not following you. How can I combine the COUNTIF, with the dates I type on the upper part?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can combine logical operators and dates like so.

```
=COUNTIF(B20:B25,">8/5/2013")
```

For example the above code counts the number of cells in the range B20:B25 with a data greater than 8/5/2013

```
=COUNTIFS(B10:B15,">=8/6/2013",B10:B15,"<=8/25/2013")
```

This one counts the number of cells in the range B10:B15 that are between (inclusive) 8/6/2013 and 8/25/2013.